# Regex password validation in Bash shell

Tags: bash

I am using Regexes in **Bash Shell script**. I am using the below Regex code to check password criteria : Password should be at least 6 characters long with at least one digit and at least one Upper case Alphabet. I validated in the Regex validation tools, the Regex I have formed works fine. But, it fails in Bash Shell Script. Please provide your thoughts.

```
echo "Please enter password for User to be created in OIM: "
echo "******Please Note: Password should be at least 6 characters long with one digit and one Upper case Alphabet******"
read user_passwd
regex="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)\S{6,}$"
echo $user_passwd
echo $regex
if [[ $user_passwd =~ $regex ]]; then
    echolog "Password Matches the criteria"
else
    echo "Password criteria: Password should be at least 6 characters long with one digit and one Upper case Alphabet"
    echo "Password does not Match the criteria, exiting..."
    exit
fi
```

Comment: A single regular expression isn't necessarily the best solution for this kind of problem. As you can see from [anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20845596/827263), a series of tests that correspond directly to your requirements can be simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: Your regexp checks for at least one lower case letter, but you don't mention that requirement in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BASH regex engine doesn't support lookarounds as in your regex.

You can use following shell glob check to make sure password matches your criteria:

```
[[ ${#s} -ge 6 && "$s" == *[A-Z]* && "$s" == *[a-z]* && "$s" == *[0-9]* ]]
```

It will make sure that input string `$s` meets all these conditions:

- at least 6 characters long
- has at least one digit
- has at least one Upper case Alphabet
- has at least one Lower case Alphabet

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I'd write `>= 6` rather than `> 5`. BTW, the question didn't mention a requirement for at least one lower case letter.

Comment: Yes `>= 6` is better. I saw OP's regex `"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)\S{6,}$"` that was checking for lowercase character as well.

Comment: In my testing both `123AsaA` and `123AsaA` came as valid passwords.

Comment: Hi Anubhava,

Thank  you so much for the answer. New Learning for me here.

I have one doubt here (hope I dont sound too dumb)

I entered range of inputs i.e. the length of the input (ranging from 6-12), the above code works between the length of input between 6-10 but after 10, the control moves to else condition and fails. Please let me know if there is any specific reason for it?

Input provided:
Success :
aas12A
AsaA123
123AssaA
AAAsss123

Failed:
aaaSSSAAA1
aaaSSSAAA112

Comment: ok can you post the code you tried in your question then I can certainly test it out and suggest you accordingly.

Comment: Hi anubhava,

I used same code as yours as below

`echo "Please enter password for User to be created : "
 echo "******Please Note: Password should be at least 6 characters long with one digit and one Upper case Alphabet******"
 read user_passwd
 if [[ ${#user_passwd} > 5 && "$user_passwd" == *[A-Z]* && "$user_passwd" == *[a-z]* && "$user_passwd" == *[0-9]* ]]; then
  echo "Password Matches the criteria"
 else
  echo "Password criteria: Password should be at least 6 characters long with one digit and one Upper case Alphabet"
  echo "Password does not Match the criteria, exiting..."
  exit
 fi`

Comment: ok got it, check updated answer. Basically needed to use `-ge` instead of `>=`

Comment: Something is weird here. I tried your code, and it would accept `t123456` even though it doesn't have any upper case character. What's more is that `[[ "A" == *[a-z]* ]]` returns true. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: No `t123456` is not validating. Make sure you have `shopt -u nocasematch` to disable ignore case matches in your BASH. You can see [this live demo](http://goo.gl/uuXwDR). When you click on `execute` it will print `invalid`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding to anubhava's answer. His check worked for me but not completely.
For e.g. "hello123" or "HELLO123" also passed the check, so it didn't detect case.
The issue was with the locale settings, more specifically the `LC_COLLATE` variable. It needs to be set to "C" to consider case. 
But a better solution was to use character classes rather than range expressions.
The explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash) helped me to solve my problem. Eventually using character classes worked for me.

```
[[ ${#s} -ge 6 && "$s" == *[[:lower:]]* && "$s" == *[[:upper:]]* && "$s" == *[0-9]* ]]
```