# Bash Shell help regular expressions not working on password check

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to make regular expression work with my password checker script but for some reason it is just not accepting it. What I am trying to do is require the following characters, the minimum of:
two upper case letters, two lower case letters, minimum 2 numbers and minimum two special characters. The special characters I am looking towards are just "!@" and that is it.
Here is the script,

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
password_length=${#password}
if [ $password_length -lt 8 -o $password_length -gt 20 ] ;then
        echo -e "Invalid password - should be between 8 and 20 characters in length.";
        echo ;
    else
        # Check for invalid characters
        case $password in
            *[^a-zA-Z0-9]* )
                echo -e "Password contains invalid characters.";
                echo ;
                ;;
            * )
                echo "Password accepted.";
                echo;;
        esac
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a good answer. At the moment I'm playing around with using `grep` as it has a far more powerful regex engine.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    echo "Password must contain 2 upper case characters and two numbers"
    read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
    echo

    FAIL=no

    # Mininum 8 characters
    [[ ${#password} -ge 8 ]] || FAIL=yes

    # Must contain 2 upper case letters
    echo $password | grep -q "[A-Z].*[A-Z]" || FAIL=yes

    # Must contain 2 digits
    echo $password | grep -q "[0-9].*[0-9]" || FAIL=yes

    # Must contain one non-alphanumeric character (no spaces)
    echo $password | grep -q "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]" || FAIL=yes

    [[ ${FAIL} == "no" ]] && break

    echo "Password invalid"
done

echo "Password $password is valid"
```

Anyway, what I would do is to test the possible password against each requirement separately, as it's easy to get lost in regular expressions, and you might miss some edge cases.

Comment: That does similar to what I wanted. If there would be a way to add at the minimum of one special character, that would be awesome. I was thinking of using grep, I know that grep -E has a better support of the regex. Thanks!

Comment: What is a special character? If you only have a small number of characters, you could list them all in a positive regex: `grep "[!@#$%^&*()]"`. Otherwise you could use a negative one: `grep "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`

Answer (score 0):

BASH regex engine doesn't support lookarounds as in your regex.

This example is for : 
 Password should be at least 6 characters long with at least one digit and at least one Upper case Alphabet.

You can use following shell glob check to make sure password matches your criteria:

[[ ${#s} -ge 6 && "$s" == *[A-Z]* && "$s" == *[a-z]* && "$s" == *[0-9]* ]]

ref : [Regex password validation in Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845497/regex-password-validation-in-bash-shell)

Comment: When I tried all of these, I started getting that the password does not match. I am trying to have an example for the following: "12asAS!@" 
Thanks!

Comment: So, Are facing issue with your script?

Comment: Yeah, sorry looks like I had pasted the wrong script, the first "new" script that I updated with is the script I need help with. I edited the post.
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I've also commented on your reference.

Comment: Actually I used this type in mine. I need to check myscript & update you on this.

Comment: First up, I assume that you have tried to give the asterisks before and after the `*[A-Z]*`. Indent the line by 4 spaces to turn it into a code block.

Comment: Secondly, you will notice that a password like `bbbbbbb6` will be accepted, even though it doesn't have an upper case character.

Comment: @chw21 yes and that is what I am trying to avoid. What can it be replaced with to make specific characters to work. I'm trying to get the first script to work. Minimum of 2 upper case, minimum of 2 digits and lower case and minimum of 2 special characters, It can be any special characters but no spaces. Thanks

Comment: So, if it has to be 2 lower case letters, 2 upper case letters, 2 digits, and 2 special characters, you can drop the minimum length of 8 requirement ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm just wondering how the "FAIL=yes variable works. I am new to scripting, taking a scripting class right now, trying to get deeper into it. Is that what checks weather the statement is true then continue if it passes all those three greps, if no it goes back with the requirements?
Thanks man! That really helped me a lot