# Unix script to validate a password?

Tags: shell, validation, unix, passwords

Unix script to validate a password, the password should be at least 8 characters long, should be alphanumeric, should contain lower case and upper case letters. If any of these conditions are not met, the script should flag the password as "weak password"

Comment: What have you tried?  Where's your code?  What's causing the problem?  We will help you fix an honest attempt to solve the problem — we won't write the code for you.  One of the bigger issues with this program is "how do you get the password to the script without exposing it to snoopy programs?"  Don't use a command line argument to hold the password to be tested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845497/regex-password-validation-in-bash-shell

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa,

Please find below my answer:

#!/usr/bin/ksh

export v_pwd=$1
l_pwd=${#v_pwd}

echo ${l_pwd}
echo ${v_pwd}

if [[ $l_pwd -ge 8 ]]; then
 if [[${v_pwd} =~ [a-z] ]] && [[ ${v_pwd} =~ [A-Z] ]] && [[ ${v_pwd} =~ [0-9] ]]; then
 echo "valid paasswd"
 
 else
  echo "not a valid pwd"
fi

else
echo "not a valid pwd"

fi